# TFS REST Api Update Build Definition Or Pass Variable While Queuing the Build C#

Tags: c#, api, rest, tfs, build

I've ran into a problem while trying to update my existing build definition in TFS by a console application written on C#. I am queuing a build successfully but the arguments i pass in parameters are not applied in the build as I can see. I tried to update the definition before I trigger it but i receive bad requests on it also.Which approach is better and if someone did it before I will ask for assistance with it. The only thing i need is to pass some parameters. I prefer not to pass strings as well too. Thanks :)

I am following the TFS REST Api documentation -> https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/build/definition-templates

Comment: How did you use the REST API?

Comment: Can you share the section of the code that has the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. [Customize your build process on fly](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/scripts/index#use-the-oauth-token-to-access-the-rest-api)

```
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/build/definitions/$($env:SYSTEM_DEFINITIONID)?api-version=2.0"

$definition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json
Write-Host "Befor json = $($definition | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)" 

    $definition.build[1].enabled = "True"   
    $definition.build[1].inputs.msbuildArgs = "\OutPath bla-bla-bla"

    $Updatedefinition = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Method PUT -Body (Convertto-Json  $Updatedefinition  -Depth 100) -ContentType "application/json"

Write-Host "After json = $($Updatedefinition | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Bad Request means you have a bad syntax. The syntax of [Update a build definition](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/build/definitions#Updateabuilddefinition) should be look like:

```
PUT https://{instance}/defaultcollection/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionid}?api-version={version}
```

You can refer to the sample request to write your own syntax:

```
PUT https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/_apis/build/definitions/29?api-version=2.0
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "id": 29,
  "revision": 1,
  "name": "myFavoriteDefinition",
  "definitionType": "build",
  "documentQuality": "definition",
  "queue": {
    "id": 1
  },
  "build": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "Build solution **\\*.sln",
      "task": {
        "id": "71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "solution": "**\\*.sln",
        "msbuildArgs": "",
        "platform": "$(platform)",
        "configuration": "$(config)",
        "clean": "false",
        "restoreNugetPackages": "true",
        "vsLocationMethod": "version",
        "vsVersion": "latest",
        "vsLocation": "",
        "msbuildLocationMethod": "version",
        "msbuildVersion": "latest",
        "msbuildArchitecture": "x86",
        "msbuildLocation": "",
        "logProjectEvents": "true"
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "Test Assemblies **\\*test*.dll;-:**\\obj\\**",
      "task": {
        "id": "ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "testAssembly": "**\\*test*.dll;-:**\\obj\\**",
        "testFiltercriteria": "",
        "runSettingsFile": "",
        "codeCoverageEnabled": "true",
        "otherConsoleOptions": "",
        "vsTestVersion": "14.0",
        "pathtoCustomTestAdapters": ""
      }
    }
  ],
  "repository": {
    "id": "278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249",
    "type": "tfsgit",
    "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-Git",
    "localPath": "$(sys.sourceFolder)/MyGitProject",
    "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/master",
    "url": "https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git",
    "clean": "false"
  },
  "options": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "definition": {
        "id": "7c555368-ca64-4199-add6-9ebaf0b0137d"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "parallel": "false",
        "multipliers": "[\"config\",\"platform\"]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "variables": {
    "forceClean": {
      "value": "false",
      "allowOverride": true
    },
    "config": {
      "value": "debug, release",
      "allowOverride": true
    },
    "platform": {
      "value": "any cpu",
      "allowOverride": true
    }
  },
  "triggers": [],
  "comment": "renamed"
}
```

Comment: Yes, but i want to update only certain properties - in the request above i want to update the variables {} . I don't wanna know to know any other information or send all the data to the TFS servers.