# Add additional mappings to Get Sources at runtime (Azure DevOps pipeline - TFVC)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfvc

Is it possible to add additional mapping to Get Sources at runtime?
Like in a prejobexecution task?

We are currently using a Powershell script that determines which additional mappings to setup based on iteration, area and different business requirements, maps them to the current workspace and then runs tf get.
This works, however, the changesets and work items from the additional mappings are not linked to the run.

We have also tried a different approach, where a “starter”-pipeline runs the scripts and modifies another pipeline (updates the tfvcMapping) and then invokes it using a build completion trigger.
All changesets and work items are linked, however, the approach does not seem right.

Answer (score 0):

> Add additional mappings to Get Sources at runtime (Azure DevOps pipeline - TFVC)

I have encountered a issue very similar to yours before (I use git). Personally, I prefer your second solution, which saves all the linked information (changesets and work items) at the cost of an additional pipeline.

For the first way, just as you test, we will lose some relevant information, which is not what we expected. Although we can use the [checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/checkout-or-edit-command?view=azure-devops) command to get the latest `changesets`, we cannot simply complete it for **workitems**, because it is done by Azure devops. It is difficult for us to obtain the associated `workitems` through `changesets` and associate them with our build.

The solution for me, we create a pipeline(as you said `starter`-pipeline) to invoke the REST API [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to update the get source for another pipeline, then hen add build completion trigger:

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.1
```

Check the [similar request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351534/tfs-rest-api-update-build-definition-or-pass-variable-while-queuing-the-build-c/38917320#38917320) here.

Hope this helps.